# LINQ - Group By multiple keys not giving desired results

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I am trying to group by multiple keys using Linq.

I have a Category Id and a Type Id associated with that and then a list of items associated with the Type Id.

As you can see from my results, they aren't being grouped.

Here is the query I am using :

```
Dim uploads = items.GroupBy(Function(g) New With {g.CategoryId, g.TypeId}) _
                                       .OrderBy(Function(g) g.Key.CategoryId) _
                                       .ThenBy(Function(g) g.Key.TypeId) _
                                       .Select(Function(g) New UploadListItemViewModel With {
                                            .CategoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
                                            .TypeId = g.Key.TypeId,
                                            .Uploads = g.ToList()
                                        })
```

Here is the results view

[image]

e.g. For Category 1 / Type 8 , the Uploads count should be 3

Any help with what I have done wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: `Key .Uploads` it is typo?

Comment: Why is it a typo? Is it wrong for some reason?

Comment: You're missing the `Key`  keyword in the group selector (`New With {Key g.CategoryId, Key g.TypeId})`). The grouping doesn't work without it. I assume that `Uploads` is an Integer, so you should have `.Uploads = g.Sum(Function(m) m.Uploads)` there. Otherwise, post the class model.

Comment: @Jimi I just found out that I was missing the `Key` keyword from another source as well. It works when I put it in. Thank you for also confirming this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the `Key` keyword in the group selector.

Final fixed code is

```
Dim uploads = items.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key x.CategoryId, Key x.TypeId}) _
                                       .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key.CategoryId) _
                                       .ThenBy(Function(x) x.Key.TypeId) _
                                       .Select(Function(g) New SKUProductUploadListItemViewModel With {
                                            .CategoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
                                            .TypeId = g.Key.TypeId,
                                            .Uploads = g.ToList()
                                        })
```

Comment: Just wondering why you sort it; does the remote end care? It's an expensive op to perform needlessly if it doesn't